# How to remove XML nodes based on date-time stamps in the child node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, workday-api

I have an XML which contains multiple nodes - 'ns:Student_Files_Grouping', and I need to remove the latest node (date-time stamp is available inside each nodes)

Can you please help how I can achieve this using XSLT 2.0 / XSLT 3.0?
I am slowly getting back to writing XSLTs, so requesting some help.

Please see the XML below which needs to be processed by the XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns:Root xmlns:ns="java">
    <ns:Data>
        <ns:Name ns:Descriptor="John Doe">
            <ns:ID ns:type="STID">1088dd20469510fee9889ce8087f0d05</ns:ID>
            <ns:ID ns:type="School_ID">76512</ns:ID>
        </ns:Name>
        <ns:School_ID>76512</ns:School_ID>
        <ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
            <ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT ns:Descriptor="John_Doe_Notice.pdf">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">c42558614694014f1d0cef5b87014a77</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="File_ID">STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-497240</ns:ID>
            </ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT>
            <ns:Doc_Category ns:Descriptor="Student Notices">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">692302db2a6e0120acc3df907c01b301</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="Document_Category_ID">Student_Notice</ns:ID>
            </ns:Doc_Category>
            <ns:FileName>John_Doe_Notice.pdf</ns:FileName>
            <ns:ReferenceID>STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-497240</ns:ReferenceID>
            <ns:Upload_Date>2021-03-31T23:35:09-07:00</ns:Upload_Date>
        </ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
        **<ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
            <ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT ns:Descriptor="John_Doe_Notice.pdf">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">8c8c2a3ebdfb01eecf731df6ea009c3b</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="File_ID">STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-498175</ns:ID>
            </ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT>
            <ns:Doc_Category ns:Descriptor="Student Notices">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">692302db2a6e0120acc3df907c01b301</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="Document_Category_ID">Student_Notice</ns:ID>
            </ns:Doc_Category>
            <ns:FileName>John_Doe_Notice.pdf</ns:FileName>
            <ns:ReferenceID>STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-498175</ns:ReferenceID>
            <ns:Upload_Date>2021-07-07T23:28:05-07:00</ns:Upload_Date>
        </ns:Student_Files_Grouping>**
        <ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
            <ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT ns:Descriptor="John_Doe_Notice.pdf">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">122144adf33d01e598738c0b88012b7d</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="File_ID">STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-516532</ns:ID>
            </ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT>
            <ns:Doc_Category ns:Descriptor="Student Notices">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">692302db2a6e0120acc3df907c01b301</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="Document_Category_ID">Student_Notice</ns:ID>
            </ns:Doc_Category>
            <ns:FileName>John_Doe_Notice.pdf</ns:FileName>
            <ns:ReferenceID>STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-516532</ns:ReferenceID>
            <ns:Upload_Date>2021-07-07T23:27:45-07:00</ns:Upload_Date>
        </ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
    </ns:Data>
</ns:Root>
```

I would need it as below. The difference is that the node - 'ns:Student_Files_Grouping' which has the latest date-time stamp for 'ns:Upload_Date', is omitted.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns:Root xmlns:ns="java">
    <ns:Data>
        <ns:Name ns:Descriptor="John Doe">
            <ns:ID ns:type="STID">1088dd20469510fee9889ce8087f0d05</ns:ID>
            <ns:ID ns:type="School_ID">76512</ns:ID>
        </ns:Name>
        <ns:School_ID>76512</ns:School_ID>
        <ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
            <ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT ns:Descriptor="John_Doe_Notice.pdf">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">c42558614694014f1d0cef5b87014a77</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="File_ID">STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-497240</ns:ID>
            </ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT>
            <ns:Doc_Category ns:Descriptor="Student Notices">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">692302db2a6e0120acc3df907c01b301</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="Document_Category_ID">Student_Notice</ns:ID>
            </ns:Doc_Category>
            <ns:FileName>John_Doe_Notice.pdf</ns:FileName>
            <ns:ReferenceID>STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-497240</ns:ReferenceID>
            <ns:Upload_Date>2021-03-31T23:35:09-07:00</ns:Upload_Date>
        </ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
        <ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
            <ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT ns:Descriptor="John_Doe_Notice.pdf">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">122144adf33d01e598738c0b88012b7d</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="File_ID">STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-516532</ns:ID>
            </ns:STUDENT_DOCUMENT>
            <ns:Doc_Category ns:Descriptor="Student Notices">
                <ns:ID ns:type="STID">692302db2a6e0120acc3df907c01b301</ns:ID>
                <ns:ID ns:type="Document_Category_ID">Student_Notice</ns:ID>
            </ns:Doc_Category>
            <ns:FileName>John_Doe_Notice.pdf</ns:FileName>
            <ns:ReferenceID>STUDENT_DOCUMENT-3-516532</ns:ReferenceID>
            <ns:Upload_Date>2021-07-07T23:27:45-07:00</ns:Upload_Date>
        </ns:Student_Files_Grouping>
    </ns:Data>
</ns:Root>
```

Please help!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Identity transformation plus an empty template for that element suffices

```
  <xsl:template match="Data/Student_Files_Grouping[xs:dateTime(Upload_Date) = max(../Student_Files_Grouping/Upload_Date/xs:dateTime(.))]"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Make sure you declare e.g. `xpath-default-namespace="java"` in the XSLT.